# Python Pandas - how to merge the disjoint content of two dataframes (of same dimensions) into a single dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge

I have two dataframes which are the same shape (identical index and column names) and both sparsely populated. The populated cells in the two dataframes are guarenteed to be disjoint e.g. is cell A1 in df1 is populated, the corresponsing cell in df2 is guaranteed not to be. I want to merge the contents of these two dataframes into a single dataframe - any suggestions?

Here is a toy example:

Given these two input dataframes:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(index = [0,1,2,3])
df2 = pd.DataFrame(index = [0,1,2,3])

df1['Fruit'] = ['Apple','','Orange','']
df1['Veg'] = ['Onion','','','Carrot']
df2['Fruit'] = ['','Banana','','']
df2['Veg'] = ['','Parsnip','','']
```

I would like to output:

```
df3 = pd.DataFrame(index = [0,1,2,3])
df3['Fruit'] = ['Apple','Banana','Orange','']
df3['Veg'] = ['Onion','Parsnip','','Carrot']
```

dataframes look like:

df1:

```
    Fruit     Veg
0   Apple   Onion
1                
2  Orange        
3          Carrot
```

df2:

```
    Fruit      Veg
0                 
1  Banana  Parsnip
2                 
3
```

df3:

```
    Fruit      Veg
0   Apple    Onion
1  Banana  Parsnip
2  Orange         
3           Carrot
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do `concat` and `dropna` with `all` condition:

```
df=pd.concat([df1,df2],axis=0).replace('',np.NaN).dropna(how='all').sort_index().fillna('')

df
Out[21]: 
    Fruit      Veg
0   Apple    Onion
1  Banana  Parsnip
2  Orange      
3          Carrot
```